# How to make first occurence as a new column pandas?

Tags: pandas

I have the following dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
d ={
    'Item':['Carrot','Beans','Potato','Carrot','Potato'],
    'Stock':[True,True, True,False,True],
    'Price':[91,95,89,55,1005]
}
df=pd.DataFrame(data=d)
print (df)
```

How to make first occurence of Price as column called output for dataframe df **based on the colum  Item**?

Expected Output

```
     Item  Stock  Price  Output
0  Carrot   True     91      91
1   Beans   True     95      95
2  Potato   True     89      89
3  Carrot  False     55      91
4  Potato   True   1005      89
```

Comment: df[‘output’] = df.groupby(‘item’).Price.transform(‘first’)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with `first`:

```
df['Output'] = df.groupby('Item')['Price'].transform('first')
print (df)
     Item  Stock  Price  Output
0  Carrot   True     91      91
1   Beans   True     95      95
2  Potato   True     89      89
3  Carrot  False     55      91
4  Potato   True   1005      89
```

Answer (score 3):

one way would be,

```
df['Output']=df['Item'].map(df[::-1].set_index('Item')['Price'].to_dict())
```

O/P:

```
     Item  Price  Stock  Output
0  Carrot     91   True      91
1   Beans     95   True      95
2  Potato     89   True      89
3  Carrot     55  False      91
4  Potato   1005   True      89
```

Explanation:

reverse the dataframe set your index as Item, so first value stored in map, then replace your dict value in Item.

Comment: @jezrael - I thought that first, But suddenly I got thought about you, You'll definitely post that answer before me. So, made a new try from `groupby+first` just to make sure that different approach from yours :)